# Generic function generating BST over some range of values

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree

This question is related to https://leetcode.com/problems/unique-binary-search-trees-ii

I am trying to implement a generic function that generates all structurally equivalent BSTs given some range of consecutive integer values `[m...n]` where `n>=m`. The idea is that if the size of this range (i.e., `n-m+1`) is the same, then regardless of the choice of `n` and `m`, the number of structurally equivalent trees should be the same. For example, we could have `(n,m) = (1,9)` and `(n,m) = (5,13)`, where the size of both is 9. These 2 ranges would generate the same BSTs in terms of structure except that the values are different. In the case, we'd swap 1 for 5, 2 for 6, ...., and 9 for 13, or vice versa. So in other words, after generating all structurally equivalent BSTs for `(n,m) = (1,9)`, I want to be able to use this to easily swap the values in [1...9] for [5...13] without having to regenerate the BSTs.

So I want to design some function that generates the structurally equivalent trees for some input `n-m+1`, store these structurally equivalent BSTs, and then later be able to plug in any `n,m` and have it give me all the structurally equivalent with nodal values in the range [n...m]. I don't want to have to regenerate the BSTs for future inputs of the same range size.

The Leetcode problem defines a BST node as

```
  struct TreeNode {
      int val;
      TreeNode *left;
      TreeNode *right;
      TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
  };
```

Is this possible with how this `TreeNode` is defined? The value it stores is of type `int`. If it was of type `int *`, then I could think of a way to do it, but the current definition seems to be problematic.

Comment: Can you give a context how you will use these trees with shifted values?

Comment: Yes, in this leetcode problem, the problem can be solved with dynamic programming. I've identified multiple different subproblems, one of which being that multiple sets of BSTs are generated with the same range size. So I wanted to see if it was possible to copy over the BSTs and simply shift their values.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of this problem has time complexity `O(n*Cn)` where `Cn` is Catalan number. No matter how you create (or copy, or shift) trees for sub-problems, you cannot achieve better complexity, because you need to print (compare,etc) all trees in the end.

*You have the following options:*

1. **Create a copy of each tree** as suggested by [Hiroki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55561474/1765621) answer. You will ends up in same time complexity, and you will double your memory.
2. **Modify tree values on the fly**. You can create a wrapper function around the tree `val` like

   ```
   int getValue(TreeNode* node, int shift){
        return node->val + shift;
   }
   ```

and use this function when you want to e.g. print all trees. Time complexity is the same and you do not allocate additional memory for shifted trees. However, in Leetcode case this is not possible as the platform compare results using `val` and you cannot change it to use `getValue`.

3. **Change definition of the tree** and use `int* val`. It is not possible to change structure on Leetcode platform, but let us consider this case, too. If you have all trees generated for some range `[1,n]` you can transform all these trees into different range just in `O(n)`. That is nice. But if you look deeper you will realize that you need to use these trees in some way (e.g. to print it, to traverse it, etc..). So, you have just virtually transformed these trees, but in the end you will end up again with the same time complexity `O(n*Cn)`. So, even if it were possible it would not be useful.

**To conclude:** For Leetcode platform you have only option `1.` In general case you have other two options, but none of these 3 options would help you to reduce time complexity.